# Stripe - how to create a customer with an account email AND a billing email?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

For creating a customer in Stripe I use this:

```
await stripe.customers.create({
  description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)',
  email: 'example@example.com',
  name: 'John',
  phone: "1234567",
});
```

But it creates me a customer with:

```
Account details:
example@example.com
Billing emails:
example@example.com
```

[image]

I want to send another email address to Stripe API and save it to the billing emails (instead the first one).

**What do I need to send to Stripe API when creating a customer for setting one email as the account email and one for the billing email?**

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't possible to set the customer's billing emails through the API. You can only tie one email address directly to a customer through the API using this param here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-email, which will be used by default if a billing email isn't provided through the dashboard. Additionally, you can specify an email address tied to a given payment method (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-billing_details-email), but that won't be used for subscription-related communications from Stripe.

Comment: Crazy that Stripe doesn't allow this...

Answer (score 0):

If all stripe related matters are the user's billing email business, I'd use the billing address a the customer's address, and put the account address in metadata for reference. Does that solve your issue?